# Regex for template parsing

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to write a template engine. I want to compile html to a javascript function. To achieve this, I should parse template successfully.

Lets say that I have a template like this without any expression: `<div></div>` 
I want to parse it as `['<div></div>']`.

With expression: `<div>${test}</div>`, I should parse it: `['<div>','${test}','</div>']`

When on multiple expressions: `<div>${test}-${test2}</div><span>${test3}</span>`, I should be able to get `['<div>','${test}','-','${test2}','</div><span>','${test3}','</span>']`

At the moment I have `/(.*?)(\${(.*?)})(.*?)/gm` which is not working as I want. Can someone help me with the right regex?

Comment: Parsing HTML string with regex is a BAD idea. How do you wish to handle `<input value='foo'/>`?

Comment: @Rajesh It won't be a problem in my case. I am compiling my html and creating a function. Lets say: `<div>${test3}</div>` , it is `out('<div>');out(test3);out('</div>')` for me. So I only concern about `${*}` parts.

Comment: If you are only concern with `${...}`, you can try something like this: https://regex101.com/r/hoo08Y/1/

Comment: I also need other parts in array, can you help me with that too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```js
var str = '<div>${test}-${test2}</div><span>${test3}</span>';
var result = str.split(/(\${.*?})/);
console.log(result)
//["<div>", "${test}", "-", "${test2}", "</div><span>", "${test3}", "</span>"]
```

hint: 
`( )` is a group, so you must replace `/(\${(.*?)})/` to `/(\${.*?})/`
otherwise it will catch more

Comment: Please notice `<>` in editor. You can put your *HTML/CSS/JS* code and make it a working snippet that readers can test. Also, please try to explain your attempt. You are answering for readers and not just OP.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your requirement, your pattern you can have 3 types of groups:

- HTML Tags: text wrapped between `<` and `>`
- Template Text: text wrapped between `${` and `}`
- Others: Any text that is not covered in above cases

You can create a regex for capturing individual groups and capture them:

Following is a sample:

[Regex101 Sample](https://regex101.com/r/nMRCd1/1/)

```js
var regex = /((\<[^>]*\>)|(\${[^}]*})|([^${}<>])+)/g;
var data = [
  '<div></div>',
  '<div>${test}</div>',
  '<div>${test}-${test2}</div>',
  '<div><span>${test}</span><span>${test12}</span></div>',
  '<div><span>${test}</span>This is a test<span>${test12}</span></div>'
]

var result = data.map(str => str.match(regex));
console.log(result)
```